# Running PHP on Windows Azure

Tags: php, azure, web, cloud

I have a Windows Azure subscription.

My requirement is to run a PHP script on my server. This PHP script will create a JSON file.
This JSON file will be downloaded by my iOS app. (Some kind of authentication is an added bonus)

How would I go about doing this? Should I create a "Mobile Service" or should I create a "Website" or something else like "Cloud Services"?

As far as I have researched, I think the only way to do this would be the old school website way. Any input on this will be really helpful. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile services are great if you want to create a quick CRUD layer for an app with a backend cloud storage such as Azure SQL DB. It also provides support for scheduled tasks and push notification. But for what you're after (producing a JSON file), you may find it easier to go with Azure Web Sites or Azure Cloud Services (PaaS). Azure Web Sites has a model that you'll likely find easier and with the free/shared tiers, provides a lower cost point for many models. If you want something that gives you a bit more control, then Cloud Services might be a good alternative as well. But given the simple example you've provided, you should be able to accomplish this fairly quickly using Web Sites.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Cool, I'll go ahead with Azure Websites as you've suggested :)